# Triggering Step Function from Java service running on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I've setup my State Machine in the AWS console (I'm using it as a asynchronous workflow platform to trigger a few lambdas). Anyway, I want to trigger state machine with some input from a java service running on an EC2 instance. But I can't find anyway to do this. In fact it looks like the only triggering mechanism is via cloudwatch? Is that right? That doesn't seem right?

Thanks any help would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) you have both `AWSStepFunctionsClient.startExecution()` and `AWSStepFunctionsAsyncClient.startExecutionAsync()`